# replacing non-alphanumeric characters with a space, ignores quote in postgres?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to replace all non alfanumeric characters in a field with spaces.

```
select 'Gishath, Sun''s Avatar', lower(regexp_replace('Gishath, Sun''s Avatar', '[^-a-zA-Z0-9_]+', ' '))
```

Im expecting the result to be `gishath sun s avatar` but is returning `gishath sun's avatar` instead. why?

Answer (score 2):

NVM, the problem was the missing g flag.

`regexp_replace('Gishath, Sun''s Avatar', '\W', ' ', 'g')`

solves the problem